# Check if an object property in an array is duplicate with another object of the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array like:

```
var arr = [
    {z: '1', val: 'duplicate'},
    {z: '1', val: 'duplicate'},
    {z: '2', val: 'test'},
    {z: '1', val: 'duplicate'},
    {z: '2', val: 'test2'}
];
```

I want a function to determine if there are any duplicate values of the property "val" for the objects which have the same id.

So in this case, the function would return that index 0, 1 and 3 are duplicates.

Comment: Having duplicate IDs defeats the purpose of calling it an ID.

Comment: var sorted = arr.sort(); 
var results = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted[i + 1].id == sorted[i].id && sorted[i + 1].val == sorted[i].val) {
        results.push(i);
    }
}

Comment: yeah you're right rahul anyway in my database it's called something else just tried to simplify it here. renaming it

Comment: I tried reduce, map, some for loops, $.each not sure how to do it properly

Comment: You can create a dictionary in which you use `<z>-<val>` as the key and the index as the value.

Comment: Actually jango's solution doesn't work when the duplicates are not side by side.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to just iterate through the array and record the duplicates. Here is a naive solution. I'm sure you can do better.

```js
function dups(arr) {
  var map = {},
    result = [],
    el;
  
  // save map of all elements and record index of occurences
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    el = JSON.stringify(arr[i]);
    if (map[el]) {
      map[el].dups.push(i)
    } else {
      map[el] = {
        dups: [i]
      }
    }
  }
  
  // return array for elements with more than 1 occurence
  for (var key in map) {
    if (map[key].dups.length > 1) {
      result = result.concat(map[key].dups)
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Note this solution does not make any assumption about the number of keys in each object or the order of them in the array.